# How to disconnect all open GDB locks in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, file-geodatabase, lock

I am having trouble releasing GDB locks in ArcMap 9.3.

Does anyone know a way to disconnect from all open GDB connections in ArcMap 9.3.

I could close and re-open arcMap, but that seems to be a little time consuming.

Has anyone made a button to do this?

Comment: +1 I've tried clearing IMxDocument.OperationStack to make sure no layers reference a gdb connection, but that didn't work.  I suspect the problem is with the workspacefactory singleton, but have no idea how to force it to disconnect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 workarounds:
assumption  here is personal geodatabase (.mdb)

1.delete the .ldb (whilst Arcmap is open - by removing the layers) delete in windows explorer. Then do 'undo' remove layers. search *.ldb for multiple

2.move up a few folder levels in ArcCatalog and Refresh, it will unlock the file and you can edit in ArcMap.

file .gdb [or .mdb] is at c:\work\project\data, if you view the c:\work\ folder and click refresh in ArcCatalog

Schema Locks
http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Schema%20locking

Comment: Aren't the .ldb files only associated with 'personal geodatabases' (Access db) that have the .mdb extension?  I wasn't aware that the 'file geodatabase' format with the extension .gdb used .ldb files.

Comment: file gdb have .lock files
Use the Compact GP tool in ArcCatalog to remove .lock files. This removes all inactive .lock files safely. The .lock files can also be deleted with Windows Explorer, the command line, or other file removal or deletion applications. Deleting any files other that the .lock files from the file geodatabase directory renders the database unusable and requires restoration from backup.
 http://resources.arcgis.com/content/kbase?fa=articleShow&d=33018